# What am I missing with this intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

So I have my activity, and it's started by an Intent. During the activity runs, I write to this Intent using `getIntent().putExtra(...)` in the same activity, same Intent I try to get this value, it is present in the intent but somehow always 0, so I checked the usage, it only has 1 write and only 1 read to the intent. The read and write is done using a constant to avoid typos. My conclusion was, its overwritten somewhere, but i couldn't find it.

Comment: Why you want to use Intent for data reading in same Activity?

Comment: because it seemd the way to do so, i try now the suggested bundle.

Comment: @ChristianBohli Did you try answer below?

Comment: I try it, but 'new Bundle' gives me an exception.

Answer (score 0):

It's not overwritten anywhere. Following the documentation, you don't need to reinvent the wheel. Purpose of the `Intents` it's [to start and pass data](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#intent-structure) in order to make communications.

At the same time, Intent is cached in the system, with it's initial values before starting. This made to support retaining state, without loosing data. Eventually, we can assume it's immutable, to support this action.

To save state already running `Activity`, we can use bundle, (not of it's  `Intent`). But `Activity` state. [Following documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states), you can resolve your issue.